# How to detect objects with a custom YOLOv5 model?

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, yolov5

I trained a YOLOv5 model from a custom dataset with the provided training routine on [github](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) (from inside tutorial.ipynb).
Using this model for detecting objects in unseen images gets me decent results when executing:

```
!python detect.py --weights custom_weights.pt --img 224 --conf 0.5 --source data/images
```

Now I want to use my model in a small project. Using the following approach does not lead to good results. It either detects complete nonsense or nothing at all on the same images used above.

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='custom_weights.pt', force_reload=True)
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
model.eval()
pred = model(img)
bboxes = pred.xyxy
```

Am I forced to use detect.py and hence cloning the whole YOLO repository into my project?
Or is there something I am missing when calling the model like I do right now?

Comment: You can export your model to supported formats, i.e TensorFlow. Then you can load and make inference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like calling the model with a numpy array is not working, at least not straightforward. When the image is transformed to a torch.tensor, you can apply non maximum supression (from yolov5/utils/general.py) to the output and receive a valid result:

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='custom_weights.pt', force_reload=True)
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
img = torch.from_numpy(img)/255.0
img = img.unsqueeze(0)
img = torch.permute(img, (0, 3, 1, 2))
pred = model(img)
pred = non_max_suppression(pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply clone the yolov5 github repository on your desktop. Paste your custom weights files in yolov5 folder and then run the inference command using detect.py. Is your model providing good results that way? If not then most probably the size of your training data is the culprit. You should train your custom model on at least more than 2000 images for good results otherwise do transfer learning.

Comment: When using the detect.py, Im getting good results. The problem is that this script does not return any bounding box coordinates. It just draws the boxes on the image and saves it as .jpg. Thats why I would like to call the model like I mentioned in the question. 
"pred.xyxy" should then be a list of bounding box coordinates. Calling the model this way would also save me from cloning the whole YOLO repo.

Answer (score 0):

Use detect.py file and pass parameters like --save-txt to save the coordinates in a text files.
!python detect.py --weights custom_weights.pt --img 224 --conf 0.5 --save-txt --source data/images